# serverInit calls using axios are not working unless i use fullpath eg http://localhost:3000/api/test

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Inside my components I can use axios calls like this normally

```js
let response = await this.$axios.get("api/test")
```

but inside `serverInit` I get a 404 error

```js
async nuxtServerInit({ commit, state }, { $axios }) {
  let x = await $axios.$get("api/test")
}
```

The error is:

```
Request failed with status code 404
* @param {Object} [request] The request.
 * @param {Object} [response] The response.
 * @returns {Error} The created error.
 */
module.exports = function createError(message, config, code, request, response) {
  var error = new Error(message);
  return enhanceError(error, config, code, request, response);
};
```

it only works if I use the full path

```js
async nuxtServerInit({ commit, state }, { $axios }) {
  let x = await $axios.$get("http://localhost:3000/api/test")
}
```

I'm using express with Nuxt with default axios configs comes with nuxt.
inside `nuxt.config.js`

```js
axios: {
  baseURL: "http://example.com",
  browserBaseURL: "http://localhost:3000"
},
serverMiddleware: [{ path: "/api", handler: "~/api/index.js" }],
```

this is my `index.js` inside API folder

```js
const express = require("express");

const router = require("../api/routes/routesIndex");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(router);

module.exports = app;
```

Ff I use full path it will be problem when I host the website, is there something I'm missing to make it work normally?

Comment: What is your nuxt version? Did you tried with env variables?

Comment: `nuxtServerInit` is used only server side, so it uses `baseUrl` instead of `browserBaseUrl`. So it hit `http://example.com/api/test`, not your nuxt server.

Comment: Kapcash thnx it worked, changed   baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",   when i host it i think i should change it to the domain name.

Comment: @Kapcash post it as an answer, this way Sam will be able to accept it. Every effort should be rewarded here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nuxtServerInit` is only used server side, so it uses `baseUrl` instead of `browserBaseUrl`.
So it hit http://example.com/api/test, not your localhost nuxt server!

EDIT: Replying to your question in comments.

When hosted, the server still see itself as localhost. I think the only thing that will change will be the port. As it's only run server side, you can it on `localhost`.

But be careful with `browserBaseUrl`, this one has to hit the correct domain name :)